# How to debug a C Programm running on a Raspberry Pi via Eclipse CDT?

Tags: c, eclipse, debugging, raspberry-pi, cross-compiling

Hej

A general question about remote debugging on RPi. My constraints:

1. the program is developed in C89
2. the project is handled by the Eclipse IDE (CDT)
3. it runs on a Raspberry Pi
4. the RPi is connected via TCP/IP to the development PC

How to do the cross development? Any Ideas and/or tutorials?